# What going on with my light switch?

Tags: light-fixture

To describe my situation n for neutral, grd for ground, and H for hot so the only wire connected to the switch is 2 white wire the 2 black wires are swisted together and the 2 grd wires swisted together. If switch is on no matter what 2 wires I check beside the 1 white wire at the bottom of switch which reads 62 volts the rest of the wires read 124.2 regardless of which 2 I check? Why

Comment: "swisted" is not an English (or, as far as I can tell from Google, any language) word.  I assume you meant "twisted".

Comment: The why is some idiot wired the switch.  With the power coming to the switch(2 cables), only the blacks(hot) should be on the switch.  Will need to check the whole circuit from the panel to see what is messed up.

Comment: @DoxyLover  From the description, swisted sounds about right, almost a PC version of snafu.

Comment: A clear, focused picture or two of the wiring you've got, especially the picture you took before you disassembled everything (you did take that one, too, didn't you?) would go a long way toward helping people understand what's going on.

Comment: Does the switch function correctly?  What are you tying to do?

Comment: It almost sounded like a switch loop but two many wires if they are all paired black to black and white to white, if you rewired things you may have tripped the breaker due to an incorrect pairing.  Check your breaker if it is tripped DO NOT reset you may have created a direct short white is not always a neutral In a switch leg setup we will need how many cables enter the box and the wires coming in, if the breaker is tripped I would separate the wires reset the breakers and carefully make new measurements.

Comment: Sounds like a normal switch circuit, but a nitwit wired the switch wrong, and has the switch interrupting the NEUTRAL.   That is wrong, because it means the bulb is hot at all times and you're likely to get shocked changing the bulb.  The switch must be re-wired to interrupt the hot.  Also fire whoever did this.